# Spelling check -> Right spelling word add to Listbox/List

Tags: c#, spelling

The User needs to tell the program, what he wants to have on the pizza, so the program is able to check, if there is a matching pizza in the database. That for I need the ingredients with the right spelling. How do I manage that? I don't want to hardcode every ingredient.

```
string[] RePr_Salami = new string[6] {"salami", "salame", "slami", "salmi", "salam", "alami"};
string[] RePr_Kaese = new string[6] {"käse", "kaese", "äse", "käs", "cheese", "kase"};
```

These are my two Arrays for Salami and Cheese.

```
private void Rechtschreibung_Zutat_Adden()
{
    //RePr Salami
    if (RePr_Salami.Any(tb_Zutat_oder_Belag_Adden.Text.Contains))
    {
        lb_Zutaten_ausgewaehlt.Items.Add("Salami");
    }
    //RePr Käse
    if (RePr_Kaese.Any(tb_Zutat_oder_Belag_Adden.Text.Contains))
    {
        lb_Zutaten_ausgewaehlt.Items.Add("Käse");
    }
    //else if für alles andere, nicht erkannte
    else if (!RePr_Salami.Any(tb_Zutat_oder_Belag_Adden.Text.Contains) && !RePr_Kaese.Any(tb_Zutat_oder_Belag_Adden.Text.Contains))
    {
        lb_Zutaten_ausgewaehlt.Items.Add(tb_Zutat_oder_Belag_Adden.Text);
    }
}
```

This is the hardcoded spelling check. But I don't want to repeat this for every ingredient available on the planet.

Is there a easy way to add a library dll or something else?

Comment: If the provided answer bellow is the correct answer for your question, then please chose it as the correct anwer, and you are also free to give a "vote up" if this was usefull for you. Just do not leave the question without feedback, or in the case you are looking for something else, then start a bounty to improve the chance of finding the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, let me try to give you my approach to your problem and we go from there:

If I understood corretly, you have a system of elements (ingredients) that are displayed to the user with the correct translation. And for each translation you have a list of "possible" matches, in case the user type something wrong.

I believe you should not store "strings" hardcoded, but instead on the database (if possible), if NOT, then add then to a XML file (or other type) wich allows you to dynamically LOAD THEM without the need of restart the application / website /etc.....

For example: 
 - I assume that the user can set its own culture/display language.
 - Then, since you know what language to process, just load the correct file data (or load the "list" from the DB). You can also add cache logic to this.

**Example**:

- (XML Files)Trans_EN.xml, Trans_DE.xml, Trans_FR.xml, Trans_RUS.xml, etc....
- Or Table: Ingredient, Table: Culture, Table: IngredientTranslated (IngId, CulId, DisplayValue), IngredienteTranslatedVariances (IngTransId, CloseValue).